# Python not updating list values

Tags: python, list, printing

At the top of my python file, I create a list:

```
table = [[]]
```

Then I have a method, that sets the value of the list:

```
def setTable():
    table = list(csv.reader(open("vplan/temp.csv")))
    print(table)
```

If I run it, the value of table gets printed out, as it should be. However, if I try to print it outside of my method

```
print(table)
```

It only prints "[[]]" - I dont understand why.
I hope someone can explain this to me, I don't use Python very often.

Comment: Because you simply assign the result to `table` inside `setTable`, which is a local variable. You could use a `global` statement, but rather, you should simply `return` the result from your function

Answer (score 0):

The table variable inside your method is not the same as the one outside of your method in order to use the same one try doing this:

```
table = [[]]

def setTable(table):
    table = list(csv.reader(open("vplan/temp.csv")))
    return table

print(setTable(table))
```

I hope this helped for you I do a lot f python programming, so I am pretty familiar with the language. I am not sure about when you are defining the table variable in the beginning that you need to assign it like this: [[]], but if that's how you need your code to be to work then use it like that. If it doesn't work with it like this: [[]], then try it like this: []. I hope this helped you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the LEGB scope rule (which you can read here: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#using-the-legb-rule-for-python-scope), the variable that you have created is at the **Global Scope** and the one inside the function is **Local Scope**.

You cannot access the **Global Scope** variable `table` inside the function by default (it creates a local scope variable with the same name that you can access within the function).
Instead you have to tell python that you are trying to assign it to a global variable `table`.

So this is the code you need to write:

```
table = [[]]

def setTable():
    global table
    table = list(csv.reader(open("vplan/temp.csv")))
    print(table)

print(table)
```